# Does this System of Complex Variables Has Solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

Find all the complex vectors $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\top$ and $\mathbf{y}=[y_1,\ldots,y_n]^\top$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that
$$
\sum_{i\in S}x_i\bar{y_i}=1,\text{ for all } S\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}\text{ and } S\neq\emptyset,
$$
where $\bar{\cdot}$ denotes the conjugate. I think I can find a special solutions. Can I find a general formula of the solutions?

Comment: If $S = \varnothing$, the left hand side is $0$.

Comment: Looking at $\{1\},\{2\}$, and $\{1,2\}$ shows it doesn't work for $n > 1$.

Comment: Want to write that as an answer for our fine folks at the Crusade, Daniel?

Comment: @EricStucky I chose to take a slightly different argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n > 1$, we cannot have

$$\sum_{i \in S} x_i \overline{y}_i = 1\tag{$\ast$}$$

for all nonempty $S\subset \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$. Looking at the singleton sets $S = \{i\}$, it follows that a necessary condition is $x_i \overline{y}_i = 1$ for all $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$, and then we have

$$\sum_{i\in S} x_i \overline{y}_1 = \operatorname{card} S.$$

Thus, for $n > 1$ the system $(\ast)$ is inconsistent.